# Drupal 8 group filter conditions using views query filter

Tags: hooks, views

I'm facing an issue while applying filter in drupal 8 views.

I have created a view of records where i showed content using filter conditions. Basically, I want to add a filter using AND/OR conditions in views filter.

Currently, There are multiple AND/OR conditions in our views filter. If i chang any Condition from AND to OR, subsequent conditions are also getting changed to the same.

Requirement is:
Condition Between first & second group will be 'AND' . Condition from second & third will be OR.

How to do it in views?

Check screenshot for more reference:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking to add a new filter, click on the little arrow that brings down more options: and/Or Rearrange. Choose that one and you can set up the logic kind of like in this image below:: *use highlighted area :: Create new filter group*

[image]